# Django Urls with a dot

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to match a url like: `/api/1.0/page/1`

I've got my main `urls.py` file:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/1.0/', include('api_v1.urls')),
]
```

and then in my `api_v1/urls.py` file:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^page/(?P<page_id>[0-9]{4})/', views.page),
]
```

I feel like it should be simple but I can't get it to work.

Comment: The URL patterns are regexes, so you'll have to escape special regex characters, like the dot. Try `r'^api/1\.0/'` instead.

Comment: It might be worth your while to read up on [the Python documentation on regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), in particular what special characters exist.

Comment: I've tried escaping the dot @Evert (I'm reasonably good with regex). When I escape it Django lists the url patters as `^api/1\.0/ ^page/(?P<page_id>[0-9]{4})/` (notice the space)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex enforces 4 character page ids.  But your page id is just `1`.  Perhaps this pattern would work better:

```
r'^page/(?P<page_id>[0-9]+)/'
```

Comment: Egg on my face. You're spot on - I was looking the the wrong place.